# DateTime picker dialog is adding one day to my selected date

Tags: android, datepicker, datetimepicker

In a section of my app, the user need to select and start and end time for an event, so I'm showing two pickers in consecutive ways so the user can pick the date/time for start/end, but the issue is that is always adding one day to the final result.

Here is my code:

```
private Date FechaInicio, FechaFin;
private Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
private Calendar myCalendarEnd = Calendar.getInstance();
private long epochTimeStart, epochTimeEnd;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nuevo_xxxxx_step3);

    //First Date picjer that have the listener dateStart
    new DatePickerDialog(xxxxx.this, dateStart, myCalendar
            .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            myCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE)).show();

}


//Start date listener
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateStart = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                          int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DATE, dayOfMonth);

        //Start de time picker for startdate   
        new TimePickerDialog(xxxxx.this,timeStart,myCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR),myCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),false).show();

    }
};


//Time picker dialog for starTime
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeStart = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, hourOfDay);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);


        epochTimeStart =  myCalendar.getTimeInMillis();

        //Start de DatePicker for End Date with
        new DatePickerDialog(xxxxxx.this, dateEnd, myCalendarEnd
                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendarEnd.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                myCalendarEnd.get(Calendar.DATE)).show();

    }
};

//Listener for end date
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateEnd = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                          int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Save the date in other calendar instance
        myCalendarEnd.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        myCalendarEnd.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        myCalendarEnd.set(Calendar.DATE, dayOfMonth);


        //Time picker for end date
        new TimePickerDialog(xxx.this,timeEnd,myCalendarEnd.get(Calendar.HOUR),myCalendarEnd.get(Calendar.MINUTE),false).show();

    }

};


//Listener for time of End Date
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeEnd = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        myCalendarEnd.set(Calendar.HOUR, hourOfDay);
        myCalendarEnd.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
        epochTimeEnd = myCalendarEnd.getTimeInMillis();
}

}
```

My variables for the time are `epochTimeStart`, `epochTimeEnd`, but when I convert them to dates is always adding one day (I tried converting the date on the web www.epochconverter.com and I have the same result).

Comment: "when i convert them to dates" where ??

Comment: in another method in other activity (i didn't post all the code), but the convertion is not the issue because i printed the epoch time and use a online converter (like www.epochconverter.com) and the result is the same, the issue is on calculation of the epoch

Comment: where is "calculation of the epoch" ? what do you expect from the calculation . what is the data that you want to display at the end?

Comment: I expect that if i select the date lets say january 10 6pm for start and January 11 for end my variables will be: epochTimeStart = 1484065866 , epochTimeEnd = 1484152266, but instead i;m having, epochStart = 1484238666, epochEnd = 1484325066  (1 day ahead)

Comment: Okay but still you can separately display data if you want as the start date and start time end date and end time .. That works well , so how you display the output.give me an example of that too

Comment: And also with the milliseconds value it seems works fine you need to show how you convert it

Answer (score 1):

I went trough your code an it works fine. Here i used this to check whats the date and time you pick. https://currentmillis.com/

[image]

See there are two time and dates UTC one and local one.You need to use the local one since youhave not posted the way you converts it if you have a time and date difference try to convert it to the right format.

Inside your first time picker

```
epochTimeStart = myCalendar.getTimeInMillis();

            Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance();
            cl.setTimeInMillis(epochTimeStart);
            cl.add(Calendar.MONTH,1); 
            String date = "" + cl.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + ":" + cl.get(Calendar.MONTH) + ":" + cl.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            String time = "" + cl.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + cl.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + cl.get(Calendar.SECOND);

            Log.d("TimeCheck *****",date + " "+ time);
```

and it will return you a data like this `4:5:2017 16:49:38`